# Get Row for Matching Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code which is running to get the matching values from one worksheet (WorksheetA) to another worksheet (WorksheetB).  I would like to identify which cell the matching value was found in.  Is there a efficient way to get this information since the code will be traversing through ~10k rows?

The current working code is below:

```
Sub ChkRcd()

    Dim r, lastRow, colCaseID As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim strColName As String
    Dim caseIDCol As String 'Case ID Col Name In WorksheetB
    r = 2

    Sheets("WorksheetA").Select
    lastRow = getLastRow

    colCaseID = FindColHeaderWText("WorksheetB", "ExternalDataReference")
    strColName = Col_Letter(colCaseID)
    Set rng = Worksheets("WorksheetB").Columns(colCaseID)

    Sheets("WorksheetA").Select
    Range("G2").Select

    For r = 2 To lastRow
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(r, 1).Value, rng, 0)) Then
        'Do stuff when the match is found
            Cells(r, 7).Value = "Yes - Row " 'Show Row Number here
        Else:
            Cells(r, 7).Value = "No"
            'Highlights the rows with no match
            Rows(r & ":" & r).Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
                .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next r

    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: how do you want to store cells address ?

Comment: Is your code too slow?  Have you tried suspending screenupdating and calculation while you run the loop?

Comment: I will update it to suspend screen updating!

Comment: I'm open to storing the cell address in whatever way helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `Application.Match(...)` returns the row number. It can also return an error, so we have to store it to a variable (with error checking), and then use it as needed.

```
Dim rowMatch as Long
...
...
On Error Resume Next
rowMatch = Application.Match(Cells(r, 1).Value, rng, 0)

If err.Number <> 0 then
    rowMatch = 0
    Err.Clear
End if 

'Use rowMatch as needed
```

Comment: `Application.Match` does not raise an error of no match is found - that only happens if you use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.

Comment: Even when I try to use:
Cells(r, 7).Value = "Yes. Row " & rng.Cells.Row

The value keeps returning 1.  Is this because of the Application.math formula I'm using?

Comment: @JK0124 In your case, `rng` refers to the entire range that you are looking up. The `Application.Match` function returns the row number of the match. For that reason, I recommended storing the result of `Application.Match` into a variable that you can use after the fact. In my code above, I stored that number in `rowMatch`. So you can call `Cells(r, 7).value = "Yes. Row " & rowMatch.

Comment: @TimWilliams The example I posted throws an error when attempting to store the result of the `Application.Match` into a variable dimensioned as a long, and this can throw an error. Per his post, he wants to store the row number corresponding to the match. To do so, he should store the result of the function in a variable, at which point he can use it as both the predicate in his conditional as well the row number where needed. Is there a better or more efficient way to manage this?

Comment: sorry I totally mis-read the question...  Was assuming OP just wanted the code to run more quickly.

Comment: You're right, I was able to get it using:  
rowMatch = Application.Match(Cells(r, 1).Value, rng, 0)
Cells(r, 7).Value = "Yes - Row " & rowMatch

Thank you!!!